# Shortcut of selecting the find scope in TeXShop

Tags: texshop, keyboard

Preferring the Ogrekit Find Panel, I often use the option "Replace All" with the scope "Selection", or with the scope "Entire File". Is there a keyboard shortcut to exchange between these two scopes? Or how do you TeXers replace something by this option?

Answer (score 3):

Holding `Alt` on the Ogrekit Find Panel toggles scope to "Selection". Releasing it toggles it back to "Entire File" (TexShop v3.26).

Comment: Thank you Zé! We noticed that it behaves like you said. But when I click enter it give me a line-change in the input window, without run the search command. At the same time, the selection of "Selection" returns. What I really want is to select the suitable "Selection" and run the search all through the keyboard.

Comment: That's a different question ;)